# Getting a 404 error when trying to link my array.js file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I am using node.js to run locally (To start the server I am using: "node index.js" in my terminal) and I keep getting this error when I try to link my array.js file.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/array.js 404 (Not Found)
```

My file paths are as such if that matters...

```
/Campus/views(Index.pug file)
/Campus(Index.js file)
/Campus/public/js(array.js file)
```

**My HTML(pug syntax) Header:**

```
doctype html
head
  script(src='array.js', type='text/javascript')
  link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css')
  link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css')
```

I feel that I did indeed reference my .js file correctly here, but this is my first time using node.js and maybe there is something I am over looking.

**My Index.js code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', 'views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.render('index', {
        title: 'Homepage'
    });
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: You might "feel" you did, you didn't though. `script(src='js/array.js', type='text/javascript')`

Comment: Hey that was it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Just for reference, static files are served from the public folder, so use the path after `public/` for them.

Comment: Oh ok gottya. Will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put it in public/js/array.js, but you're referencing it in public/array.js. Your path should be js/array.js

Documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html